# SignalR Service large message options

Tags: azure-signalr

SignalR Service in Azure, not .Net.

I send a lot of SignalR messages via normal web sockets. However, it has a size limit for the message.  It some cases, I would like a message to be sent from the server-side to include a JSON response over websocket.  Are there options, like streaming, to send larger amounts of data?

I understand I can always send a url back to client and have it make a standard REST call to get the data. But, I think it would be cooler if I could just reply with the data inside a message.

I realize this may not what it is designed to handle (request/response), but I'd like to know what other options are supported by signalR Service. I don't see anything in the documents specific to the fully-managed service.

I'm only looking for suggested options, not judgement of the idea. :)

Thanks,
Donnie

Answer (score 0):

Please consider that SignalR is not meant to work with large amount of data-per-request. That's what the project maintainers say, even if this kind of functionality can be achieved in various ways.

This is not related to the .net/azure nature of what you are using, but it's true for every implementation of SignalR.

You can find more info about the performance considerations here:
[MSDN SignalR Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance)

My suggested option is: use SignalR for a fast, slim real-time communication system. Use another piece of software to achieve large data payloads transit with no worry.

These are the use cases covered "officially" by the product SignalR Azure Service:

- Apps that require high frequency updates from the server. Examples are gaming, voting, auction, maps, and GPS apps.
- Dashboards and monitoring apps. Examples include company dashboards and instant sales updates.
- Collaborative apps. Whiteboard apps and team meeting software are examples of collaborative apps.
- Apps that require notifications. Social networks, email, chat, games, travel alerts, and many other apps use notifications.

Does your application fall into one or more of these cases? If not, than consider using a different strategy to achieve your goal.

Comment: Yes, like I said, I know it is not designed for it.  However, I did see docs that said signalR supports streaming.  I'm just trying to see what else SignalR Service supports.